# How do I declare a variable based on user input?

Tags: java, user-input, variable-declaration

I am trying to create a program that spell checks what the user has typed in. They have to type the word 'type' in 10 times correctly and it will display a message saying how long it took.
My problem is that the end never comes, it continually ask you to type in 'type'. I believe this is because of the '`while (attempts < required)`'. I think I need to make required = correct attempt. `if attempt = type`, then it will produce 1 correct value. Any help is appreciated. also apologies, I don't know how to structure the question

```
    public static void printHeading(String heading) {

        System.out.println(heading.toUpperCase());

        for (int i = 0; i < heading.length(); i++)
            System.out.print("=");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
    }


    public static int runTutorial(Scanner in, String word, int required) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String attempt = word;
        int correct = 0;
        int attempts = 0;

        while (attempts<required) 
        {
            System.out.print("Enter '" + word + "': ");
            attempt = sc.nextLine();

            if(attempt.equals("type")) {

                System.out.println("Correct");
            }   
            else {
                System.out.println("Try again");
            }
        }
        return attempts;

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        final int TIMES = 10; //required number of correct repetitions
        final String WORD = "type"; //the word to type
        long startTime, endTime; //start and end time of typing test
        double seconds; //elapsed time in seconds
        int attempts;

        printHeading("Typing Tutor");
        System.out.println("You need to type a word " + TIMES +
                           " times correctly, as quickly as you can");
        System.out.println("Your word today will be '" + WORD + "' (do not enter the quotes)");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Type anything and press enter to begin");

        //The test
        System.out.println("Press enter to start the test");
        sc.nextLine();
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        attempts = runTutorial(sc, WORD, TIMES);
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        //Test report
        seconds = (double)(endTime - startTime) / 1000;
        System.out.println("You took " + seconds + " seconds and " + attempts +
                           " attempts to correctly type '" + WORD + "' " + TIMES + " times");
        System.out.println();
        printHeading("Come back for more pracice soon");
    }

}
```

Comment: You forgot to increment `attempts` in your `while` loop, its value is always `0` .

Comment: what has this got to do with declaring a variable?

Comment: @JohnSmith your question is unclear. you want us to help you, I would recommend first learning the basic terminology. there is declaring a variable, instantiating a variable, setting the value of a variable. No, they're not the same.
A variable has to be declared before you can even dream of using it, that much is true. But your question in the title is about declaring a variable, your explanation is about something different alltogether

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under `System.out.println("Correct");`, you need to increment the `attempts` variable, otherwise it will remain at 0.

```
if(attempt.equals("type")) {

    System.out.println("Correct");
    attempts++; // <-- here
}
```